# How are ABF (Astaro Binary Files) encoded / how can I read in plaintext?

Tags: astaro

I need to move an IPsec L2L peer from one host to another, and I need to get the old PSK because the client I am working with cannot retrieve the other end's credentials right now. I have access to the old firewall, an Astaro firewall, and its ABF configuration files in binary.

I did not choose to encrypt the ABF when downloading but it is still an unintelligible binary in an unknown encoding without even a header.

I have no idea what to do with it and it might as well be encrypted.

Does anybody have any clue how these files are encoded?